# How to merge 2 fields into array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to collapse several fields into an array, I have a document as a result of a Talend job which has a document structure similar to below.

You can see there are multiple "department" documents within the "location" document, and - if a department record is present (1 or more) I need to stuff them into an array instead.

```
{
_id: "1010101010101010",
COUNTRY_ID: "1",
COUNTRY_NAME: "US",
location: [
    {
       location_id: "99",
       location_name: "Washington",
       department: 
          {
             department_id: "100",
             department_name: "Finance"
          },
      department: 
          { 
             department_id: "101",
             department_name: "Sales"
          }
     }
  ]
}
```

I need it to become:

```
   {
_id: "1010101010101010",
COUNTRY_ID: "1",
COUNTRY_NAME: "US",
location: [
    {
       location_id: "99",
       location_name: "Washington",
       department: 
          [ 
            {
               department_id: "100",
               department_name: "Finance"
            },
            { 
               department_id: "101",
               department_name: "Sales"
            }
         ]
     }
  ]
}
```

It would seem like I want the opposite of an $unwind action but am not that familiar with mongoDB. Any help appreciated.

Comment: in your first document you have filed `department` and.. something without field name?

Comment: any better now?

Comment: I believe you gave us invalid json... why dont you populate real object?..

Comment: @smackenzie so you have two fields with same name? not much better now

Comment: I will update but need to probably be in front of the computer instead of doing this from memory, my apologies.